# Debug APK size 25% smaller than Release (both with Proguard)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

The debug APK we generated is **30 MB**, while on the other hand, the release APK is **40 MB**

Both uses the same proguard and gradle config, as below :

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig getSigningConfig()
        }
        debug {
              debuggable true
              minifyEnabled true
              shrinkResources false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              signingConfig getSigningConfig()
        }
    }
```

Please leave a comment if you need more code to analyze this problem

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some information about how you built your APKs? I noticed recently that building (or Syncing Gradle) via Android Studio, it produces smaller than expected AARs (I'm building a library) of the variant not selected as the default. When I build (./gradlew assemble) from the command line the word makes sense.

Comment: was debug apk build with android studio or gradle command? Android Studio is optimizing apk for your device (removing resources) as well as adding things (f.e instant run server) so it's a huge difference between those two